# How can i make a subdomain automatically when a user register

Tags: node.js, subdomain, vhosts, wildcard-subdomain

Hi i tried everywhere but i cant get the solution. i am using vhost and nodejs to make subdomain in vhost documentation they not provided how to make subdomain dynamically **my actual question is how can i make a subdomain with the name of the user after the user signup**

i make subdomain manually and the code is below

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const vhost = require("vhost");


app.use(cookieParser());

const institute_adminRoutes = require("./api/routes/institute-admin");

app.use(
  cors({ origin: "*", credentials: true, exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"] })
);
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const subdomain = express();

const domain = "localhost";


app.use(vhost(`jhon.${domain}`, subdomain,));    *//here is the subdomain i create with name jhon*

subdomain.use(cookieParser());

subdomain.use(morgan("dev"));
subdomain.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
subdomain.use(bodyParser.json());

subdomain.use(institute_adminRoutes);

app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("Not found");
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});

app.use("*", (error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message,
    },
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here i create it manually with name jhon  `app.use(vhost(`jhon.${domain}`, subdomain,));`

**how can i do it by taking the name of the user after signup**

Comment: I think you are doing this the wrong way. You have multiple options, first is to use Kubernetes or a reverse proxy. Reverse proxy seems to be the best option here. You have to automatically create a string for the subdomain and save it to the database. 

Set the A record as a wildcard that maps to your reverse proxy. Now, when a request comes you you take the header, find the host, match it to your database record and save the requests.

Comment: what is the mistake tell me if you know

Comment: So what's the problem with adding this code inside a register handler?

Comment: sorry i didnt get you

Comment: You will have some code where a user signs up like `app.use("/register", (req, res) => {...})` So why can't add the code which is creating the router for your subdomain inside this handler?

Comment: But it's not just adding the `vhost`, you probably have to create a respective dns record pointing to that server as well (or do you have a wildcard DNS entry?)

Comment: i didnt have wildcard i am using vhost

Comment: @derpirscher so inside that     app.use("/register", (req, res) => {...})   inside this code want to set vhost..?

Comment: if anyone know can share it with an example so it is realy helpfull to me

Comment: @Paschal can you show me with an example its really helpful otherwise any reference link is there

Comment: Yes, sure. This will help; https://caddy.community/t/reverse-proxy-for-multiple-use-case/11863/2

But also understand this approach and use of Caddy might be slightly more complicated than using Vhost. But it supports adding and serving from the user's domain and subdomains all fully automated with SSL using the Caddy API.

Comment: bro i need to make by vhosts

Comment: can anyoneknow how it done